# Get snapshots of googlevis dates

Tags: r, date, googlevis

I am using googlevis to plot a motion chart. My dataset looks like this below

```
cluster_id  id  date        diff ....
1           A  08/31/2000
2           B  08/31/2000
1           A  08/31/2001
1           B  08/31/2001
```

I want to use date for the timevar parameter; my dates are only yearly snapshots.  When I use `googlevis` it plots monthly dates and I think it's doing a linear interpolation which I don't want. I just want it to plot data for the yearly snapshots.

```
M <- gvisMotionChart(data, idvar="id", timevar="date")
```

Comment: Not enough data to see what you are talking about with regard to "yearly snapshots". And why are you using "motion" when you don't seem to want motion? (And obviously you know that you cannot use a date in that format, right?)

Comment: Thanks! yes i understand the date has to be reformatted and i do that as well  mydate<-as.Date(cluster$date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

Comment: @Dwin, I think the OP *does* want motion, but simply wants the motion to be year-on-year as opposed to month-on-month.

Comment: As @Dwin suggests, correcting the date format is important.  Why don't you try putting the date in the correct format and see if you are still getting output other than what you expect

Comment: I still do want to see the yearly snapshots on one chart. I just want it to jump to the next year instead of going month to month.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo I did try putting it in the format and it plots fine for the yearly snapshots but it also plots in between dates so I am guessing its doing some linear interpolation in the middle. I am formatting the date as shown above

Comment: Sorry to harp on about this but even if we take the example of the Fruits dataset....M <- gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", xvar ='Sales', yvar = 'Expenses', timevar="Year")...why does the timeline show interpolated values from 2008 to 2009. I just want it to jump from 2008 to 2009.